# Adding nodes in hadoop 2 (hadoop 2.4.1)

Tags: hadoop

I want to add nodes to Hadoop 2.4.1

How to proceed ? I'm afraid to lost my HDFS.

I plan to execute those steps :

- Extract hadoop on futures nodes
- Configure settings (*.xml)
- stop cluster
- edit hadoop/slaves and add nodes names
- restart cluster

Is there additional commands to execute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add nodes without worrying about losing your data. I followed the following tutorial with ease so you should be able too. The steps you have laid out are correct.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

Work perfectly, thanks SailorLeroy :)

It's possible to rebalance all cluster datas with the following command :

```
hdfs balancer -threshold 10
```